# Element Set Theory Problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this set problem I need to find an answer for, and the last time I did element set theory was awhile back. It goes:

Solve for $n$ where $n$ = $\min (B' \cap N)$

$n \in \mathbb{N}$

$x \in A$

$A = \{a: 1 ≤ a ≤ 5, a \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$B = \{b: b = x^2\}$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $B$ ? Are $b$ and $x$ naturals ? that means that $b$ is a "square" number : $4,9$ etc

Comment: Is $B'$ the *complement* (with respect to $\mathbb N$) of $B$ ?

Comment: What is the role of $A$ ?

Comment: If so, $n$ will be the least natural number in $B'$, i.e. the least natural number that is **not** a square. We have $1^2=1$ and $2^2=4$. Thus, the conclusion is ...

Comment: Wouldn't B' be elements that are not B?

Comment: Yes the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of $B$.

Comment: So, the conclusion is therefore n=2, as it is the lowest not square number?

Comment: Or, is the conclusion that there is no conclusion as n is always a square natural number? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try to address the problem by steps.

Let $\mathbb N$ the set of *natural* numbers, i.e. $\mathbb N = \{ 1,2,3,\ldots \}$.

Let $B = \{ b \in \mathbb N \mid b=x^2, \text { for some } x \in \mathbb N \}$.

Thus, $B = \{ 1,4,9,16,\ldots \}$.

$B'$ is the *complement* of $B$.

Both $B$ and $B'$ are subsets of $\mathbb N$; thus :

> $B' \cap \mathbb N = B'$.

*Conclusion* : the least $n \in (B' \cap \mathbb N)$ will be the least element in $B'$, i.e. the least natural number that is **not** a square.

Obviously, $B' = \{ 2,3,5,\ldots \}$, and thus :

> > $n=2$.